# Finding the combination where p of the items are identical.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Suppose we have $n$ objects in which $p$ items are identical. Of course, $n-p$ elements are distinct. Then what is the combination of $n$ objects taken $r$ at a time? That is, what is $C(n,r)$, but keep in mind all $n$ object are not distinct here?

For example, suppose a population consist of five values $1,3,3,4,5$. A random sample of $3$ values is drawn without replacement from this population. Then how many such samples of cardinality $3$ are possible? There are $7$, right? But what is the general formula?

Comment: Are you searching for binomial coefficient?

Comment: What do you mean "the combination of $n$ objects"? You said you only have $n$ objects.

Comment: Your question is formulated unprecisely. Are we taking $r$ objects out of the starting $n$ ones, and counting the number of different combinations? Moreover: are the remaining $n-p$ objects all different?

Comment: I too am unsure of exactly what is being asked.  If we have, say, the multiset $\{a,a,a,a,a,b,c,d,e,f\}$ and we ask how many submultisets of size three can be made, break up into cases on the number of element $a$ are used.  There are then $\binom{5}{3}+\binom{5}{2}+\binom{5}{1}+\binom{5}{0}$ possibilities.

Comment: Question is edited with an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without loss of generality, let our multiset of size $n$ be labeled as $\{\underbrace{a,a,\dots,a}_{p~\text{copies}},b_1,b_2,\dots,b_{n-p}\}$

We ask how many submultisets of size $r$ exist taking into account the fact that the $a$'s are identical.

Break into cases based on the number of copies of $a$ are used.  If we use $i$ copies of $a$, we will still need to select $r-i$ additional elements to be used from the $n-p$ non-$a$ elements.  There will be $\binom{n-p}{r-i}$ possible outcomes in this case.

Iterating over all possible values of $i$, the final total will be:

$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{p}\binom{n-p}{r-i}$$

using the convention that $\binom{n}{r}=0$ for $r$ negative.

In your example, $\{1,3,3,4,5\}$ and $r=3$ there are $\binom{3}{3}+\binom{3}{2}+\binom{3}{1} = 1+3+3=7$ possibilities.

---

It is worth mentioning that for the purposes of probability arguments, if the elements are selected uniformly and independently at random without replacement, these possible outcomes will not be equally likely to occur.  $\{3,5\}$ will occur with probability $\frac{2}{\binom{5}{2}}=0.2$ whereas $\{3,3\}$ will occur with probability $\frac{1}{\binom{5}{2}}=0.1$

Comment: But the probability of getting either $\{1,3,4\}$ or $\{1,3,3\}$ are the same, right?

Comment: @Matt no.  Imagine that you have $\{1,\color{red}{3},\color{blue}{3},4,5\}$.  $\{1,3,3\}$ **only** occurs when you have both the red and the blue three used, however $\{1,3,4\}$ could have been either $\{1,\color{red}{3},4\}$ or it could have been $\{1,\color{blue}{3},4\}$ and so is twice as likely to occur.

Comment: @Matt It is common when picking items independently and uniformly at random with some identical items to *temporarily assume the items are different*.  In doing so, you can have a convenient equiprobable sample space to work with, and can use counting principles as you would normally.